# Mocking up Apache session data for unit testing

Tags: perl, apache, unit-testing

I'm working with a web application that, normally, runs in mod_perl under Apache.  A co-worker and I are trying to do some unit testing.  Are there any good tools or techniques out there for mocking-up sessions and requests and the like that could help us exercise this code outside of the web server context?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using mod_perl 1, there is [Apache::FakeRequest](http://metacpan.org/module/Apache%3a%3aFakeRequest) which comes with mod_perl.  It is not a complete mock of the request object, so you have to add some methods of your own.  Even more if your code uses [Apache::Request](http://metacpan.org/module/Apache%3a%3aRequest).  Yet more for cookies and uploads.  Mostly you're going to be spending a lot of time with [Test::MockObject](http://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMockObject).  Fortunately, the Apache object interfaces are pretty straight forward.

If at all possible, you should consider switching to a [Plack](http://metacpan.org/module/Plack) based framework (Catalyst, [Dancer](http://metacpan.org/module/Dancer), etc...) which provide far more robust testing and debugging facilities.  If you're using mod_perl2, you're in luck!  It's easy (relative to mod_perl 1) to wrap a mod_perl2 application with Plack.  [Plack::App::FakeApache](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aApp%3a%3aFakeApache) does most of the work for you.  [Here is a discussion](http://peter.makholm.net/2010/11/30/wrapping-mod_perl-in-plack/) sketching out the various techniques and benefits.

Comment: There's also [Apache2::FakeRequest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::FakeRequest) for mod_perl 2.